# What are my options for a better touchpad since libinput has removed hysteresis configurations?

Tags: touchpad, synaptics, libinput

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on a Lenovo X1 Carbon 6th gen.

Synaptics had a fantastic options called `noise cancellation`. I'm now understanding that we should be using libinput since Synaptics will no longer be updated.

Well, libinput removed their hysteresis options and replaced with something that the user can't configure (beyond recompiling from source). My touchpad using libinput right now is atrocious. I just can't use it in its current state, it's not precise enough with small movements.

Should I revert to Synaptics or is there something that can be done under libinput?

Comment: It's because it's supposed to work out of the box. Please, [report a bug](https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/reporting-bugs.html#reporting-bugs-touchpad) to libinput. The maintainer is very active, so hopefully some solution will appear quickly; just make sure to provide all the needed information.